# How to create a new table from two tables by using lag dates?

Tags: r

I am struggling with few things
1) I want to make a new table (DF3) from two tables one is DF1 which has lot of data points about 12,000 rows it has got column names as below. The AQS_SITE_ID is the location of sites where data is collected there are multiple sites with each unique site ID. I want to match this site id with, sites in the DF2 matrix. I made the sites in DF2 by mapping zipcodes to coordinates (SITE_LATITUDE AND SITE_LONGITUDE). So i should create new table DF3 by taking previous day or previous 1 week concentration of PM25 (DF2 date 2011/02/14 look for previous 1 day or 1 week in DF1, but also need to match the AQS_SITE_ID and site location).

> [1] "str_Date"
>       [2] "AQS_SITE_ID"
>       [3] "POC"
>       [4] "DailyMeanPM25Concentration"
>       [5] "UNITS"
>       [6] "DAILY_AQI_VALUE"
>       [7] "DAILY_OBS_COUNT"
>       [8] "PERCENT_COMPLETE"
>       [9] "AQS_PARAMETER_CODE"
>       [10] "AQS_PARAMETER_DESC"
>       [11] "CSA_CODE"
>       [12] "CSA_NAME"
>       [13] "CBSA_CODE"
>       [14] "CBSA_NAME"
>       [15] "STATE_CODE"
>       [16] "STATE"
>       [17] "COUNTY_CODE"
>       [18] "COUNTY"
>       [19] "SITE_LATITUDE"
>   DF2

```
 Date         EMMI      ACT      pm25   SITE_ID
    2011/02/12   12345     21       11     XYZ
    2011/02/14   14321     22       12     YER
    2011/02/19   12345     21       13     XYZ
    2011/02/23   43211     13       12     YER
    2011/02/23   56341     13       12     YER
```

Finally i should have table DF3 with

> Date EMMI ACT PM25 SITE_ID Lag1daypm25 Lag2daypm25 Lag1Weekpm25 Sum1weekPM25

Comment: As with your other questions, you might want to look into `?merge` and try something out before posting a request.

Comment: Hi Frank, Yes i looked at the merge, it works great if there is no lag in time which i want to do. I want to do lag in time (here date) which cannot be done using merge alone.

Comment: I don't know why you need to merge the data before calculating the lags. As for the details of calculating the lagged PM2.5, have you looked at `?lag`?

Answer (score 0):

I just take a look at your duplicated version:

to answer your qauestion, you just have to use the merge command:

```
result = merge( DF1, DF2, all=TRUE)
```

This should answer your question

Comment: Yes but how do you do lag. Dates between tow DFs are matched and merged , however i want to Lag days by one day or one week. The dates are not continuous in DF1